# JQuery Slideshow Choppy in IE

Tags: jquery, animation, internet-explorer

I have created a slideshow using JQuery, and it works greate in all browser except, of course, IE. I'm not worried about IE6 or 7 right now, but even in IE8, the transition animations are very choppy.  Does anyone have any idea what the solution could be?  This is very smooth in Firefox, Safari and Opera:

http://www.pfconrey.com/weddings

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you,
Peter Conrey

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on my IE8 that it started the animation while it was still getting the images. Once it was done, it wasn't perfect, but it pretty close to what I got in FF. So if there is a way to trigger the animation to begin after the last image has loaded, that may help.

To be sure it's not just me, try setting the src of the images to all local files (basically test the page offline). That way the load time is instant.

Comment: It is a lot better when run locally, but how do I get that type of performance from IE when pulling the files remotely?  It seems that even when the page is fully loaded, I get very choppy transitions.